# Select rows from a filtered portion of Table A where a column matches a relationship with a column from the row in Table B that matches by ID

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to get all rows in a table where one column matches a relationship with the value of the column in the row in a different table that has the same value of another column.

Concretely, I have two tables, orders and product_info that I'm accessing through Amazon Redshift

Orders

```
| ID   | Date     | Amount | Region |
=====================================
| 1    | 2019/4/1 | $120   | A      |
| 1    | 2019/4/4 | $100   | A      |
| 2    | 2019/4/2 | $50    | A      |
| 3    | 2019/4/6 | $70    | B      |
```

The partition keys of order are region and date.

Product Information

```
| ID   | Release Date | Region |
| ---- | ------------ | ------ |
| 1    | 2019/4/2     | A      |
| 2    | 2019/4/3     | A      |
| 3    | 2019/4/5     | B      |
```

The primary key of product information is id, and the partition key is region.

I want to get all rows from Orders in region A where the date of the row is greater than the release date value in product information for that ID.

So in this case it should return just one row,

```
| 1    | 2019/4/4 | $100   | A      |
```

I tried doing

```
select *
from orders
INNER JOIN product_info ON orders.date>product_info.release_date
  AND orders.id=product_info.id
  AND orders.region=A
  AND product_info.region=A
limit 10
```

The problem is that this query was absurdly slow (cancelled it after 10 minutes).  The tables are extremely large, and I have a feeling it was scanning the entire table without restricting it to region first (in reality I have other filters in addition to region that I want to apply to the list of IDs before I do the inner join, but I've limited it to only region for the sake of simplifying the question).

How can I efficiently write this type of query?

Comment: Can you add your table definitions so we can see what indexes you have in place and an explain plan.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are using MySQL or Amazon Redshift? The capabilities and syntax varies between the two systems.

Comment: Edited the question to show that I'm using Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make an SQL query faster is to exclude rows as soon as possible.

So, rather than putting conditions like `orders.region=A` in the JOIN statement, you should move them to a `WHERE` statement. This will eliminate rows before they are joined.

Also, make the `JOIN` condition as simple as possible so that the database can optimize the comparison.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
INNER JOIN product_info ON orders.id = product_info.id
WHERE orders.region = 'A'
  AND product_info.region = 'A'
  AND orders.date > product_info.release_date
```

Any further optimization would require consideration of the `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY` on the Redshift tables. (Preferably a `DISTKEY` of `id` and a `SORTKEY` of `date`).